# In Hybirs how to import a class which is in one extension to another

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I am working on a internal app in `Hybris`. Like `HMC`. I have create an extension and added the required extensions in the `extensioninfo.xml`, but when I am trying to import a `bean` in those required extensions, I am seeing `class cannot be resolved`. I have cleaned the project. But I am unable to resolve this issue. Can someone guide me. I can provide more details on request.

```
<extensioninfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="extensioninfo.xsd">

   <extension abstractclassprefix="Generated" classprefix="Sma" managername="SmaManager" managersuperclass="de.hybris.platform.jalo.extension.Extension" name="sma" usemaven="false">
      <!-- for more information on maven managed libraries please consult https://wiki.hybris.com/x/Nq8sDQ -->

      <!-- you should add all required extensions to this list, except platform extensions which are automatically required -->         
      <!-- <requires-extension name="cms"/> -->         

        <requires-extension name="services"/>
      <coremodule generated="true" manager="com.company.sma.jalo.SmaManager" packageroot="com.company.sma"/>

      <webmodule jspcompile="false" webroot="/sma"/>

   </extension>

</extensioninfo>
```

Comment: Can you show the code of extensioninfo.xml file?

Comment: I dont know why my xml is not getting added completely,

Comment: Can you try command `ant clean all` and see any error or not? If no error, maybe you see `class cannot be resolved` causes by IDE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `extensioninfo.xml` file, we add only the extension dependencies. So, when you add a new Hybris extension, you need to add it to your `localextensions.xml` file, required extensions too. Don't miss that :

> All extensions located in ${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/platform/ext are
>   automatically             loaded, no need to add them to localextensions.xml file.

Then, `ant clean all` will build your extensions ressources.

If you cannot resolve your extentions in the IDE, you need to add them to the `build path` **manually**.

Comment: I have done it. My app context is fine. I am able to see my app. but I am unable to import classes from the required-extensions. The problem is build path. I dont know it should be added by default to build path the required-extensions or should do it manually

Comment: You should add the required extensions (projects) to the build path manually .

Answer (score 0):

> [yjavac] 1. ERROR cannot be resolved to a type in Hybris?

Extensions can have dependencies on one another. The build only works if the required extension is available.

Ensure the below steps to works it smoothly.

---

### Dependencies to Non-Platform(not located in `/platform/ext`) Extension

- The required extension should be there in `localextensions.xml`
- Add the required extension in `extensioninfo.xml` (e.g `<requires-extension name="hmc"/>`) of the dependent extension
- In your eclipse(IDE), add required extension in `build path` of the dependent extension to resolve IDE dependecy.

  **Note:** Adding required extension in IDE build path won't resolve extension dependency of your platform. It only resolved by `extensioninfo.xml`
- Rebuild the system (`ant clean all`)

---

### Dependencies to Platform Extension

By default, all extensions have the dependency on Platform extension(located at `/platform/ext`). Therefore, you do not required to specify `requires-extension` for the Platform extensions in `extensioninfo.xml` file.

---

### [Source Post](https://hybrisdeveloper.blogspot.in/2018/03/yjavac-1-error-cannot-be-resolved-to.html)